# login/register action using Segmented control and switch statement

Tags: swift3, switch-statement, xcode8, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to realize login/register action using Segmented control and switch statement:

```
@IBAction func signInRegisterAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

switch signInRegister.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            signInButton.setTitle("Sign in", for: .normal)
        case 1:
            signInButton.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Than I want to realize that in this button action:

```
   @IBAction func signInButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if signInRegisterAction.0 {
        one action
        }else{
        second action}
}
```

Please, help me to do logic in signInButtonAction!

Comment: Are you looking for the actual logic for logging in and registering or just how to determine which segment of the segmented control is selected when the `signInButtonAction` method is called?

Comment: The second way) I don't imagine how to ask this switch work in signInButtonAction

Comment: What is preventing you from using the same `switch` statement as in the `signInRegisterAction`? Why can't you simply check the `selectedSegmentIndex` again?

Comment: I solve this) if signInRegister.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { Thank you for responding